# Python line read size in bytes

Tags: python, file, size, byte, line

I'm working in linux.
I would like to display the percentage of file parsed. That's why after reading a bit I decided that the most accurate way to do that would be get the total size (bytes) of the file i'm parsing then calculate the size (bytes) of each line after reading it.

This is my dummy simplified code.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

read_bytes = 0
total_file_size = os.path.getsize(myfile)

with open(myfile, 'r') as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
        read_bytes += sys.getsizeof(line)

        print "do my stuff"

print total_file_size
print read_bytes
```

Output is:

193794194

203979278

Obviously there's something count in line that's increasing total size.
I've tried with:

```
read_bytes += sys.getsizeof(line) - sys.getsizeof('\n')
```

And output is:

193794194

193309190

I must be missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `len` instead of `sys.getsizeof()`:

`sys.getsizeof()` return used byte by interpreter to hold that object.

```
>>> len('asdf')
4
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getsizeof('asdf')
37
```

In addition to that, if you are running the program in the Window, you should use binary mode.

```
open(myfile, 'rb')
```

**NOTE**

Using [file.tell](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.tell), you don't need to calculate current position.

Comment: You're totally right. I was so obfuscated trying to use getsizeof. Because each line is a string len(line) works perfect ! Thank you.

Comment: @Guillermo, Using `file.tell()`, you don't need to calculate read count.

Answer (score 0):

replace:

```
read_bytes += sys.getsizeof(line) - sys.getsizeof('\n') 
with read_bytes += sys.getsizeof(line) - sys.getsizeof('\n') - 49 as 49 is ascii of '0'
```

Comment: Please remember that: "Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better." [How-do-I-write-a-good-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Ok :) I was just adding extra information if anybody scroll upto this!